# Count Instances Of Occuring String With Unique IDs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I need to count the number of times that a specific string occurs but they when one ID has the same string more than once, only count it once. Basically, I need to count the number of occurrences of a string that occur uniquely to an ID. I believe this should be a simple thing to do but I don't know what I'm doing. Here is my current code:

```
SELECT
RXNAME as Name,
DUPERSID as ID,
COUNT(RXNAME) as Number
FROM
`OmniHealth.PrescriptionsMEPS` 
GROUP BY
ID,
Name
ORDER BY
Number
```

When run, it says everything was counted as 1. Thanks for the help!

UPDATE:
Dataset: https://storage.googleapis.com/omnihealth/MepsPrescriptionData.csv

OUTPUT when run with code above:

```
Row Name    ID  Number   
1   SUMATRIPTAN 68896102    1    
2   IBUPROFEN   65063102    1    
3   PENICILLN VK    66179101    1    
4   FUROSEMIDE  63217102    1    
5   HYSINGLA ER 70373101    1    
6   FUROSEMIDE  76090101    1    
7   SKELETAL MUSCLE RELAXANTS   78414101    1    
8   AMOXICILLIN 69467103    1    
9   TRAMADOL HCL    67667101    1    
10  PANTOPRAZOLE    60737102    1    
11  CARBAMIDE PEROXIDE 6.5% OTIC SOLN   63990104    1    
12  PROMETH/COD 68433101    1    
13  AZITHROMYCIN    79045102    1    
14  METRONIDAZOL    75414101    1    
15  DEXILANT    69625101    1    
16  TRAMADOL HCL    66890203    1    
17  AZITHROMYCIN    73838101    1    
18  COLCRYS 63856102    1    
19  PERMETHRIN  62103107    1    
20  ACETAMINOPHEN TAB 500 MG    62456102    1
```

Comment: Having a group by on name and ID will yield a distinct count of all names for each id, your query is correct. Perhaps your data does not have the duplicates.

Comment: ....perhaps a sample starting dataset and a desired result would enlighten us.

Comment: I see the problem, I bet there is a Name field in the dataset. You can't use a field alias at the same level that it has been defined. You need to GROUP BY ID ,RXNAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if it is what you asked  - but if you are looking for DISTINCT COUNT - go with below:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  RXNAME AS Name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT DUPERSID) AS Number
FROM `OmniHealth.PrescriptionsMEPS` 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Number DESC
```

Comment: That's very close to what I need. But that still counts the distinct medicine names. It's a difficult thing to word but I need basically the number of people who bought each medicine. Individual people have individual IDs and each medicine obviously has a name. I want to see how many times each medicine has been bought, but only count one time per medicine per person. I tried counting the distinct IDs but that still gave me 1 for each. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: provide example of input and output! just simplified example will make it  - so we will be able to help you!

Comment: Just put data and output in the original post

Comment: Thank you that did it! I appreciate your help! For my info, what does the group by 1 do?

Comment: sure. glad we did it. consider voting up the answer

Comment: `1` in `GROUP BY 1` says GROUP BY first filed in SELECT statement. so in this case it is equivalent to `GROUP BY Name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...You are grouping on a different field than you are counting. I think you are meaning to group by RXNAME.

```
SELECT
RXNAME as Name,
DUPERSID as ID,
COUNT(RXNAME) as Number
FROM
`OmniHealth.PrescriptionsMEPS` 
GROUP BY
ID,
RXNAME
ORDER BY
Number
```

Comment: Just tried that and still get one count for everything. I may have worded it poorly so here another go. It's a difficult thing to word but I need basically the number of people who bought each medicine. Individual people have individual IDs and each medicine obviously has a name. I want to see how many times each medicine has been bought, but only count one time per medicine per person.

Comment: Ah, it sounded like you wanted the number of distinct RXNAME and number of times it showed for each ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT DUPERSID as ID, COUNT(DISTINCT RXNAME) as Number
FROM `OmniHealth.PrescriptionsMEPS` 
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY Number;
```

This assumes that "same string" means "same value for RXNAME".

Comment: That still gives me one count for everything. It's a difficult thing to word but I need basically the number of people who bought each medicine. Individual people have individual IDs and each medicine obviously has a name. I want to see how many times each medicine has been bought, but only count one time per medicine per person.

Comment: @CarsonP . . . Did you change the `GROUP BY` clause?